# How to get two data series in tikz plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I create a second data series from the code below? I have tried separating the two curves with curly brackets but it was not the correct code.

```
 \begin{figure}[h!tp]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[    
            title={Relative energy Versus Basis Set Number},
            xlabel={Basis Set},
            ylabel={Relative energy (kJmol$^{-1}$},
            xmin=0, xmax=4,
            ymin=0, ymax=400,
            xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
            ytick={0,50,100,150,200,250,300,350,400},
            legend pos=north west,
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,
        ]

        \addplot[
            color=black,
            mark=square,
            ]
            coordinates {
      (2,114.5)(3,22.5)(4,0)}
      {(2,334)(3,85)(4,0)};


        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have as many `\addplot` constructs as you wish to have separate curves. Unlike TikZ, pgfplots needs to know explicitly what the curves and their properties are. Hence

```
    \addplot[draw=black,mark=square]coordinates{(2,114.5)(3,22.5)(4,0)};
    \addplot[draw=black,mark=square]coordinates{(2,334)(3,85)(4,0)};
```

adds the second curve.